# PHP merging 2d associative arrays with a shared PK

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If I have two 2d array like this:

```
$CVS_results = [[["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001081",["email"]=>"tpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001082",["email"]=>"jpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001083",["email"]=>"rpastern@stjudes.org"]]

$BC_results = [[["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001085",["email"]=>"tpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001086",["email"]=>"jpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001087",["email"]=>"rpastern@stjudes.org"]]
```

That come from two different sources that I'd like to merge like this:

```
$merged= [[["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001081",["email"]=>"tpastern@stjudes.org",["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001085"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001082",["email"]=>"jpastern@stjudes.org",["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001086"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001083",["email"]=>"rpastern@stjudes.org",["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001087"]]
```

I'm finding tons of examples of this:

```
$merged = [[["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001081",["email"]=>"tpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001082",["email"]=>"jpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["CVS_ID"]=>"FZ00000001083",["email"]=>"rpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [[["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001085",["email"]=>"tpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001086",["email"]=>"jpastern@stjudes.org"],
              [["BC_ID"]=>"QR00000001087",["email"]=>"rpastern@stjudes.org"]]
```

but that's not what I need. I have a feeling I'm going to have to searches with nested for loops, but I'm hoping for something a little neater and more efficient.

**UPDATE:**
The following code gets me the first or last record, correctly formed, depending on whether I use $merged = or merged +=... there should be 16

```
$BC_results = BC_cust_query($qlist, true);

$CVS_results = CVS_query_GP_ID($BC_results);

$merged = array() ;
foreach ($BC_results as $row){
    foreach($CVS_results as $item){
        if (strcmp($row['email'], $item['email'])){
            $merged = array([$row['email'],$row['BC_ID'],$item['CVS_ID']]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($merged);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This worksm but it feels like a big, cludgy sledgehammer:

```
$merged = array() ;
foreach ($BC_results as $row){
    foreach($CVS_results as $item){
        $ii +=1;
        if ((strcmp(strtoupper(trim($row['email'])), strtoupper(trim($item['email'])))) == 0){
            $merged = array_merge($merged, array([$row['email'],$row['BC_ID'],$item['CVS_ID']]));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

TIA,
Jimbus